# Description a set of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Can we describe the  set of functions $A$ as the set of all function that map $x=2$ to any number in $\mathbb Q$ except zero and consequently there are as many zero functions as possible where x ≠ 2?

$A = \{ f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q \mid f(2) \ne 0 \}$

Comment: I'm confused, is A the set of all functions f(x)=a, where a is not equal to 0, or is f(x) a function such that the codomain does not contain 0?

Comment: According to your def, YES the *zero* function: $\text Z(r)=0$ for every $r$ does not belong to $A$ because $\text Z(2)=0$.